# Display new arrivals by category in Magento

Tags: magento, catalog

I would like to display the most recently added products from a specific category on my Magento store.

I have studied the code at http://www.tridian.com/developer-blog/adding-new-arrivals-to-magento/. From what I've found so far, this seems to be the best place to start. The problem is that it will grab the newest products from the entire catalog, whereas I want to limit the catalog scope to a specific category ID.

I understand that I will need to change `if($curr_category == 'new arrivals')` to check for the specific category, and I suspect I will need to put a flag or condition within that `if` statement.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can query products from specific category like this:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('category_id', '319');
```

and add filters by date (date is a pseudo field name here find the exact field name from product information) if needed like this:

```
->addFieldToFilter('date',array('from'=>'10-10-2010','to'=>'11-10-2010'))
```

and to improve your understandings how collections are handled I suggest you to read:
[Great read about collections in Magento is written by Alan Storm](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections)

Comment: Anton, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. Adding `->addFieldToFilter('category_id', '319')` throws an error: Invalid attribute name: category_id.

Comment: hi , i wrote this from the top of my head you need to verify in what field this data is or what the field name actually is